# Matlab mixed effects model with grouped measurement errors

Tags: matlab, regression, mixed-models

Is it possible to specify the measurement error separately for different data points when using Matlab's linear or nonlinear mixed effects model fitting tools (e.g. `fitlme` and `nlmefit`)?  I am working with data that have a prescribed measurement error, but it varies across different data points because sensors of varying accuracies were used to collect the data.  Measurement error is normal, zero mean, and variance depends on the sensor type.  Therefore, I would like to use a sensor-type grouping to specify these measurement errors, but there does not appear to be a way to explicitly specify these.  I'm currently working with a linear model, but anticipate transitioning to a nonlinear one, so suggestions for both are appreciated.

To be clear, the measurement error I'm referring to here is actual uncertainty in the measured responses of my data, and not the "measurement" or "process" error associated with fitting the mixed effect model.  Though, functionally, they may ultimately have the same form.